# Additional field in articles from custom template

Tags: sulu

I have a problem. In elastic search, we have data returned as follows:

```
"uuid": "8f39a450-64c2-407c-9836-32ed3b4db1ce",
"locale": "de",
"title": "Blah nedvsger",
"route_path": "/articles/blah-nedvsger",
"type": "news",
"type_translation": "sulu_article.news",
"structure_type": "news",
"changer_full_name": "Adam Ministrator",
"creator_full_name": "Adam Ministrator",
"changed": "2021-07-06T09:52:42+0000",
"created": "2021-07-06T09:49:50+0000",
"excerpt": {},
"seo": {},
"authored": "2021-07-06T09:49:50+0000",
"author_full_name": "Adam Ministrator",
"teaser_description": "",
"published": "2021-07-06T09:49:51+0000",
"published_state": true,
"localization_state": {},
"author_id": 1,
"creator_contact_id": 1,
"changer_contact_id": 1,
"pages": [],
"content_data": "{\"title\":\"Blah nedvsger\",\"routePath\":\"\\/articles\\/blah-nedvsger\",\"hero_image\":{\"id\":null},\"overline\":\"asfdafasdf\",\"headline\":\"adfgasdf\",\"auth\":[\"c1\"],\"introduction\":\"asdfd\",\"blocks\":[],\"related\":{\"audienceTargeting\":null,\"categories\":null,\"categoryOperator\":\"or\",\"dataSource\":null,\"includeSubFolders\":null,\"limitResult\":null,\"presentAs\":null,\"sortBy\":\"published\",\"sortMethod\":\"asc\",\"tagOperator\":\"or\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"default\",\"fascination\",\"news\"],\"tags\":null}}",
"main_webspace": "magazine",
"additional_webspaces": [
"olympics2021"
],
"content_fields": []
```

Now, I want to show value of field "headline" from content_data, and we've done this:

**ADDDED articles.xml column as:**

```
<property
                name="contentData"
                visibility="always"
                translation="Content data"
        >
            <transformer type="json.headline" />
        </property>
```

**Created Json.js, with code (npm run build, and all):**

```
import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import type {FieldTransformer} from 'sulu-admin-bundle/types';

export default class JsonHeadlineTransformer implements FieldTransformer {
    transform(value: *): Node
    {

        console.log(value);

        let json = {};

        try
        {
            json = JSON.parse(value);
        }
        catch (error)
        {
           return;
        }

        if('headline' in json)
        {
            return json.headline;
        }
    }
}
```

And it returns empty string. In console it returns undefined. Where are we wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I did it in simplest way, I created in src/Admin/Controller file ArticleController and inherited Bundle one, and just changed getFieldDescriptors method, like:

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Sulu\Bundle\ArticleBundle\Controller\ArticleController as SuluArticleController;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandlerInterface;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchBundle\Service\Manager;
use Sulu\Bundle\ArticleBundle\Document\Index\DocumentFactoryInterface;
use Sulu\Bundle\ArticleBundle\ListBuilder\ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor;
use Sulu\Component\Content\Mapper\ContentMapperInterface;
use Sulu\Component\DocumentManager\DocumentManagerInterface;
use Sulu\Component\DocumentManager\MetadataFactoryInterface;
use Sulu\Component\Hash\RequestHashCheckerInterface;
use Sulu\Component\Rest\ListBuilder\FieldDescriptorInterface;
use Sulu\Component\Rest\ListBuilder\ListRestHelperInterface;
use Sulu\Component\Security\Authorization\SecurityCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

/**
 * Provides API for articles.
 */
class ArticleController extends SuluArticleController
//    AbstractRestController implements ClassResourceInterface, SecuredControllerInterface
{

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $displayTabAll;


    public function __construct(
        ViewHandlerInterface $viewHandler,
        DocumentManagerInterface $documentManager,
        ContentMapperInterface $contentMapper,
        MetadataFactoryInterface $metadataFactory,
        ListRestHelperInterface $restHelper,
        Manager $manager,
        DocumentFactoryInterface $documentFactory,
        FormFactoryInterface $formFactory,
        RequestHashCheckerInterface $requestHashChecker,
        SecurityCheckerInterface $securityChecker,
        bool $displayTabAll = true,
        ?TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage = null
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $viewHandler,
            $documentManager,
            $contentMapper,
            $metadataFactory,
            $restHelper,
            $manager,
            $documentFactory,
            $formFactory,
            $requestHashChecker,
            $securityChecker,
            $displayTabAll,
            $tokenStorage
        );
    }


    /**
     * Create field-descriptor array.
     *
     * @return ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor[]
     */
    protected function getFieldDescriptors(): array
    {
        return [
            'uuid' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('id', 'public.id')
                ->setVisibility(FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_NO)
                ->build(),
            'typeTranslation' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('typeTranslation', 'sulu_article.list.type')
                ->setSortField('typeTranslation.raw')
                ->setVisibility(
                    $this->displayTabAll ?
                        FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_YES :
                        FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_NEVER
                )
                ->build(),
            'title' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('title', 'public.title')
                ->setSortField('title.raw')
                ->build(),
            'creatorFullName' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('creatorFullName', 'sulu_article.list.creator')
                ->setSortField('creatorFullName.raw')
                ->build(),
            'changerFullName' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('changerFullName', 'sulu_article.list.changer')
                ->setSortField('changerFullName.raw')
                ->build(),
            'authorFullName' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('authorFullName', 'sulu_article.author')
                ->setSortField('authorFullName.raw')
                ->build(),
            'created' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('created', 'public.created')
                ->setSortField('created')
                ->setType('datetime')
                ->setVisibility(FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_NO)
                ->build(),
            'changed' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('changed', 'public.changed')
                ->setSortField('changed')
                ->setType('datetime')
                ->setVisibility(FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_NO)
                ->build(),
            'authored' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('authored', 'sulu_article.authored')
                ->setSortField('authored')
                ->setType('datetime')
                ->build(),
            'localizationState' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('localizationState')
                ->setVisibility(FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_NO)
                ->build(),
            'published' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('published')
                ->setVisibility(FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_NO)
                ->build(),
            'publishedState' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('publishedState')
                ->setVisibility(FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_NO)
                ->build(),
            'routePath' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('routePath')
                ->setVisibility(FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_NO)
                ->build(),
            'contentData' => ElasticSearchFieldDescriptor::create('contentData')
                ->setVisibility(FieldDescriptorInterface::VISIBILITY_YES)
                ->build(),
        ];
    }

}
```